# Prevent Oracle LogMiner from creating archived logs in flash recovery area

Tags: oracle, plsql, audit

I'm trying to use Oracle LogMiner (`DBMS_LOGMNR` package) for implementation of audit trails functionality based on redo logs. But each time when I query `V$LOGMNR_CONTENTS` it creates several big (up to 50M) archived logs files in flash recovery area (`SELECT NAME FROM V$RECOVERY_FILE_DEST`) in spite the fact that there were only several transactions per hour in my test DB. After several times of using Oracle LogMiner all space in flash recovery area becomes used and Oracle stops working.

Is there any way to prevent Oracle LogMiner from creating archived logs in flash recovery area?

I initialize Oracle LogMiner in the following way:

```
SYS.DBMS_LOGMNR_D.BUILD(options => SYS.DBMS_LOGMNR_D.STORE_IN_REDO_LOGS);

SYS.DBMS_LOGMNR.START_LOGMNR(startScn => PREV_SCN, endScn => NEXT_SCN,
      options =>
                 SYS.DBMS_LOGMNR.COMMITTED_DATA_ONLY +
                 SYS.DBMS_LOGMNR.DICT_FROM_REDO_LOGS +
                 SYS.DBMS_LOGMNR.SKIP_CORRUPTION +
                 SYS.DBMS_LOGMNR.CONTINUOUS_MINE
   );
```

Distance between PREV_SCN and NEXT_SCN is always small in my case and covers only several transactions.

When I use `ALTER DATABASE NOARCHIVELOG;` to turn off archived logs, `DBMS_LOGMNR_D.BUILD` raises `ORA-01325`: archive log mode must be enabled to build into the logstream.

Comment: While your question is interesting in itself (why does LogMiner create redo/undo?), I'm wondering why you don't use the AUDIT command for your audit trail?

Comment: Vincent, AFAIK Oracle Audits allow me to see only statements that were executed with their bind variables. But I should display old and new values of fields for each row in my audit trail report. Please, correct me if I wrong about Oracle Audits.

Comment: You're right the AUDIT command doesn't record the :new and :old values. Fine-grained auditing (Entreprise Ed. feature) may have more options.

Comment: Oracle FGA doesn't provide information about :new and :old values either, but it looks like it can be obtained with using of FGA + Oracle Flashback Queries. Thanks.

Comment: Vincent, Oracle FGA doesn't suitable for my case anyway. Even with using of Flashback Queries there is no appropriate way to determinate what was changed except of two full selects over audited table: SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE AS OF SCN AUDIT_SCN MINUS SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE AS OF SCN AUDIT_SCN +1; Where AUDIT_SCN is a value of SCN from FGA audit trails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason why Logminer creates entries in the redo log is because you have asked it specifically:

```
 SYS.DBMS_LOGMNR_D.BUILD(options => SYS.DBMS_LOGMNR_D.STORE_IN_REDO_LOGS);
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If you don't want logminer to store its data in the redo logs, use `DBMS_LOGMNR_D.STORE_IN_FLAT_FILE` instead. See [this blog note](http://oracle-tns.com/step-by-step-logminer/) for example for a step by step guide on how to setup logminer using flat files.

Comment: Thank you! I thought that STORE_IN_REDO_LOGS option stores logs in one place and overwrite it each time when I calling DBMS_LOGMNR_D.BUILD but it isn't true. Dictionary is re-created each time when I calling DBMS_LOGMNR_D.BUILD and old one is not removed. I'll use STORE_IN_FLAT_FILE instead.